# overloading greater than operator casts user-defined type to primitive, information is lost

Tags: c++, casting, operator-overloading, user-defined-types

In a C++ library where a user-defined type exists that adds a textual representation of the symbolical value of a variable, to the primitive data types int, double, ..., bool:

```
template<typename T>
class Var {
    T value;

    //a datastructure containing Expressions and string representations of operators
    Expression expr; 
}
```

The operator for `addition (+)` is overwritten:

```
#define OVERLOAD_ARITHMETIC_OPERATOR(op, opName) \
template<typename X, typename Y>\
auto operator op(const X x, const Y y) ->\
se::Var<decltype(__filter(x).getValue() op __filter(y).getValue())> \
{\
    const auto __x = __filter(x);\
    const auto __y = __filter(y);\
    auto result = se::constructVar(__x.getValue() op __y.getValue());\
    if(__x.isSymbolic() || __y.isSymbolic()) {\
        result.setExpression(BINARY_EXPRESSION(opName, __x.getExpression(), __y.getExpression()));\
    }\
    return result;\
}\

OVERLOAD_ARITHMETIC_OPERATOR(+, ADD)
```

The following program:

main.cpp:

```
#define double Double
#define int Int
#define float Float
#define bool Bool

#include "aprogram.c"

#undef double 
#undef int
#undef float
#undef bool

int main(){
     std::cout << afunction();
}
```

aprogram.c:

```
int afunction(){
    double t1 = ... ;
    double t2 = ... ;
    return t1 + t2;
}
```

returns `t1.expr + t2.expr` as expected.

**Problem**

When overloading the operator `greater (>)`:

```
#define OVERLOAD_COND_OPERATOR(op, opName) \
template<typename X, typename Y>\
se::Var<bool> operator op(const X x, const Y y)\
{\
    const auto __x = __filter(x);\
    const auto __y = __filter(y);\
    auto result = se::constructVar(__x.getValue() op __y.getValue());\
    if(__x.isSymbolic() || __y.isSymbolic()) \
        result.setExpression(BINARY_EXPRESSION(opName, __x.getExpression(), __y.getExpression()));\
    return result;\
}\

OVERLOAD_COND_OPERATOR(>, GREATER)
```

and changing the return in *afunction()* to `return t1 > t2` we expect a similar result, `t1.expr > t2.expr`, but instead the result gets casted to a bool and the information stored in Var.expr is lost.

**Although I believe the operators for `+` and `>` are similarly written, can you help me understand why `>` behaves differently? Can you help me get to the wanted behaviour?**

Please provide feedback to my question: help me help you helping me.

**Information Added after posting**

1/
`__filter()` is a method returning the datastructure Var. In my example Var is greatly simplified, filter just returns the object with `T value` and `Expression expr` in it.

2/

```
typedef se::Var<double> Double;
typedef se::Var<int> Int;
typedef se::Var<char> Char;
typedef se::Var<float> Float;
typedef se::Var<bool> Bool;
```

Comment: Note: I guess double leading underscores are reserved for the compiler

Comment: Am I the only one that finds `OVERLOAD_COND_OPERATOR` utterly misleading when defining an **add-op** ?? It would seem there should be a different expansion for conditional vs. value-result operators.

Comment: Could you please share more on your code? What __filter is, etc?

Comment: @WhozCraig typo on StackOverflow, my bad.

Comment: @oopscene I added some information regarding __filter(), but basically it shouldn't matter.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Why not using the boost parser?

Comment: Please post a http://sscce.org -- eliminate all macro use, as macros might be part of the problem, but if they are then eliminating them will tell us that.  Actually test the code before you post, so it has no typos.  Do not use identifiers starting with `__`, that is reserved for compiler implementors **only**.  Finally, are you trying to overload operators on primitive types?  You cannot do that, I am pretty sure: UB.  No wait that is your illegal `#define`s making it look like you are.

Comment: Yakk, I am trying to overload operators on primitive types. In reality, aprogram's afunction() contains a bunch of code, arithmetic and conditionals. Every operator (+, >, ...) in existence is overwritten to implement the behaviour that generates these Expressions.

Comment: Type @ before a name to notify them.  Next, note that the function or operator called never depends on the body of the function, so of your problem is that the wrong operator is called you can eliminate the body of the operator to simplify your sscce.  You cannot override operators on (only) primitives under the C++ standard. Note that the namespace of operators is in matters, as is the namespace of the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is going to do any number of unexpected things, because it has undefined behavior.

This is not allowed:

```
#define double Double
#define int Int
#define float Float
#define bool Bool
```

Macro names have to be identifiers, and those are keywords, not identifiers.

Section 17.6.4.3 makes this very clear:

> A translation unit shall not `#define` or `#undef` names lexically identical to keywords, to the identifiers listed in Table 3, or to the *attribute-tokens* described in 7.6.

and

> If a program declares or defines a name in a context where it is reserved, other than as explicitly allowed by this Clause, its behavior is undeﬁned.

Comment: Ben, thanks for the reply! Please refer to the typedefs I added in my question field. Does that change anything?

Comment: @Caroline: Nope, not unless you're telling me you are using the typedefs instead of these macros.  It's the macro name, not the expansion, that this rule in the Standard is concerned with.